# Android Jetpack Compose - Floating Action Button of custom image

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, scaffold

I write this code.

```
    Image (
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.image),
        contentDescription = "fab",
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(80.dp)
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = rememberRipple(true),
                onClick = { /* TODO */ }
            )
    )
```

But, I use Scaffold.
So I want to use floating action button or extended floating action button.
How can I use floating action button and custom image.
I have a circular photo to use for the button.

```
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {},
        content = {},
        floatingActionButton = {
            Image {
                /* How can I wrire */
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {},
    content = {},
    floatingActionButton = {
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Image (
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxxx),
                contentDescription = "fab",
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
But, there is a margin around this image.

Comment: @vr_min_chan Add an appropriate contentScale (check the updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
 FloatingActionButton(
                        backgroundColor = Color(0xFFF7FAFF),
                        onClick = { **TODO** },
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd).padding(start = 15.dp, top = 15.dp, end = 8.dp, bottom = 15.dp).background(Color.Transparent)) 
                        {
                        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_fab_btn), contentDescription = "fab", contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,)
                        }
```

[image]